# hbase client scan could not initialize org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Classes

Tags: filter, hbase

I use hbase client Scan to get data from remote hbase server cluster. When I set a Filter to the scan, the client will throw a exception:

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc:RemoteException:IPC server unable to read call parameters:
>   Could not init org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Classes.

The server side's hbase log:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Could not initial class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Classes
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.readFields(Scan.java:590)

But it works well without a Filter. By the way, the filter is NOT a custom Filter.

My hbase version is 0.94.10 and hadoop is 1.2.1. I have copy hadoop-core.jar to the lib directory under hbase.

Comment: @Tshepang.Sorry for that.I've post it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Classes` puts some initial code in its static block. So it will be initialized only once. When it initialize something the first time, if RunTimeException is thrown, it will not initialize anymore unless you restart your hbase cluster. In the initial block, it will create directory,  and if it fails to create the directory, runtimeException will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check **JDK** version. In **IntelliJ** DB for example I was having this issue because I had both **JDK 15** and **JDK 8** installed and the **phoenix** version I was using was intended to **Java 8** so once I changed the **JVM** it worked.

**In IntelliJ:** You can change the Driver VM by going to Data Sources and *Drivers -> NameYourCustomDriver -> Advanced (Tab) -> VM home path (field)*

See this image example for reference: [IntelliJ example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phmFC.png)

Answer (score 1):

During initialization of `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Classes`, if the configured value for "hbase.local.dir" doesn't exist, a runtime exception will be thrown and `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Classes` will fail to initialize. That runtime exception causes a ClassDefNotFoundException to be thrown which is what is eventually reported in the logs.

Make sure these exist and are writeable by HBase:

- hbase.local.dir (default: ${hbase.tmp.dir}/local)
- hbase.tmp.dir (default: ${java.io.tmpdir}/hbase-${user.name})